# React, how to return a value from function to component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to do a basic `if, else` operation inside my component, for that I need to return a **[boolean]** after checking if the image loaded correctly or not.

```
export const Suggest = (props) => {
  function handleLoad(url) {
    let image = new Image();
    image.src = url;

    image.onload = function() {    
      return false;
    }

    image.onerror = function() {    
      return true;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      { 
        props.state.suggestions.map((item, i) => 
          <div key={i}>
            <span>Boolean {i} = {handleLoad(item.image) ? 'True' : 'False'}</span>
          </div>
        )
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Unfortunately calling the function `handleLoad(item.image)` returns `null`.

How should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `handleLoad` function does not return anything, and will return `undefined` by default. 
The `onload` and `onerror` are assigned new functions.

Since you're loading an image (an asynchronous operation), there is no way to return the result synchronously. You will need to use promises, e.g.

```
function handleLoad(url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    let image = new Image();
    image.src = url;

    image.onload = function() { 
        resolve();
    }

    image.onerror = function() {    
        reject(new Error('Image loading failed'));
    } 
  });
}
```

Then, you can load your images on `componentDidMount`, and use the `then` callback to set your state accordingly:

```
// This is just a helper method to set the loaded
// flag and update the state for a given suggestion.
// Added it to avoid repeating ourselves.
setSuggestionLoaded = (suggestionIndex, isLoaded) => {
    let suggestions = this.state.suggestions;
    suggestions[suggestionIndex].loaded = isLoaded;
    this.setState({ suggestions: suggestions });
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.state.suggestions.map((suggestion, i) => {
        handleLoad(suggestion)
        .then(() => {
            setSuggestionLoaded(i, true);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            setSuggestionLoaded(i, false);
        }));
    })
}
```

Then you can render your state, it will be updated when the loading operations finish or fail.

```
  return (
    <div>
      { 
        props.state.suggestions.map((item, i) => 
          <div key={i}>
            <span>Boolean {i} = {item.loaded ? 'True' : 'False'}</span>
          </div>
        )
      }
    </div>
  )
```

Another option to do this would be via plain old callbacks, e.g.:

```
function handleLoad(url, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    let image = new Image();
    image.src = url;

    image.onload = function() { 
        if(successCallback) successCallback();
    }

    image.onerror = function() {
        if(errorCallback) errorCallback(new Error('Image loading failed'));
    } 
}


componentDidMount() {
    this.state.suggestions.map((suggestion, i) => {
        handleLoad(suggestion,
            () => {                
                setSuggestionLoaded(i, true);
            },
            (err) => {
                setSuggestionLoaded(i, false);
            }
        );
    })
}
```

But I'd personally recommend the promises approach. I'd go even further and recommend you to read about the new `async / await` syntax which essentially is a pretty way to write promise-based asynchronous JavaScript.

Comment: Out of scope question, but shouldn't you use the `setState()` function instead, when setting the `loaded` value to each suggestion?

Comment: Ah yeah, very good shout! I forgot to add that, after setting  the `loaded` property, you need to use the `setState` function. Editing now.